# What are the advantages to using the new classes in System.Diagnostics.PerformanceData?

Tags: .net, performancecounter

In .NET 3.5, a new set of classes for interacting with performance counters was introduced in the `System.Diagnostics.PerformanceData` namespace. According to Microsoft's documentation, "the classes in this namespace support the new architecture (version 2.0) for performance counters that was introduced in Windows Vista." This new set of classes is described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancedata.aspx).

It seems to me that these classes are much more complicated to use; they require the developer to write an XML manifest file, compile it, generate resource files, and use the `LodCtr` tool to register the counters. I haven't been successful in finding tools or processes that simplify this.

My question is, what are the advantages to using this new set of classes? For this additional work, what is the benefit? What are the reasons I might want to go to this effort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main advantage is the ability of creating aggregate counters, which are useful in multi process applications. These counters can aggregate data coming from multiple processes instances into single value.

And you're right - it's much more difficult to create these counters than it was before. What might help is the DevUtils ETW IMBA package, which eases the pain a bit. Have a look here: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/897687/To-Help-Create-Provider-Performance-Counters-v